# Show that the image of a periodic $C^1$ function is compact

Tags: multivariable-calculus

I am given a question as follows.

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ be a periodic $C^1$ function. Show that the image of $f$ is compact or give counter example.

My textbook defines a comapact set is a set that is closed and bounded. And if $f$ is periodic function, then there is $r \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(t) = f(t + r).$ I believe that this is true statement. The reason is that if $f$ is periodic and differentiable function, there are maximum and minimum at certain point where the derivative is equal to $0$. So this will handle the boundedness. I learned that a set is closed if it contains limit points, or the complement is open. My book gives one theorem as follows.

Given $S \subset \mathbb{R}^n$, $a \in S$, and $f : S \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^m$, the following are equivalent.

- $f$ is continuous at $a$.
- For any $\{x_k\}$ in $S$ that converges to $a$, the sequence $\{f(x_k)\}$ converges to $f(a)$.

I think this will handle the closedness. However, I have no idea how I am going to give formal proof for this question. Can anyone help me with this?? If this statement is false, what would be a counter example??

Comment: $f(\mathbb{R})=f([0,r])$ [0,r] is compact. And the continuous image of a compact set is compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement is true.

Note that we can consider the restriction $f:[0,r] \to \mathbb R^n$, since $f$ is periodic.

First we show boundedness. Assume the contrary that the image is unbounded. Then there is $r_1, r_2, \cdots \in [0,r]$ so that $|f(r_i)| \ge i$ for all $i \in \mathbb N$.

Since $\{r_i\}$ is a bounded sequence in $[0,r]$, a subsequence of $r_i$ converges to some $s\in [0,r]$. (That's Bolzano Weiestruass theorem)

So there is $\{s_i\} \in [0,r]$ so that $s_i \to s$ and $|f(s_i)| \to \infty$. But as $f$ is continuous,

$$\lim_{i\ to \infty} f(s_i) = f(\lim_{i \to \infty} s_i) =f(s)$$

Thus $|f(s_i)|$ is bounded and that's a contradiction. Thus the image is bounded.

To show that the image is also closed, let $y_1, y_2 , \cdots$ be elements in the image and $y_i \to y$. Then there is $r_1, r_2, \cdot \in [0,r]$ so that $f(r_i) = y_i$. As in the previous case, one can find a subsequence so that $s_i \to s$. Then by continuity of $f$ again,

$$y =\lim_{i \to \infty} y_i = \lim_{i\to \infty} f(s_i) = f(s).$$

Thus $y$ is also in the image of $f$. Thus the image is closed.

Comment: Ok, the proof for the boundedness is clear. Thanks. But for the closeness, you mean that the theorem I wrote in the question can be applied right?? I understnad that if the domain of $f$ is bounded set, then I can use That's Bolzano Weiestruass theorem and the theorem I in the question can be used to prove the closeness. But how do you know that the domain is $[0,r]$?? If $f$ is periodic, I guess we only know that image is bounded but not the domain isnt it?? I think I need more explanation.

Comment: The domain isn't bounded. But the image of $f: \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^n$ is the same as the image of $f: [0,r] \to \mathbb R^n$. Thus it sufices to consider the restriction to $[0,r]$. @eChung00

Comment: Please see the edit of my answer. @eChung00

Comment: Ok I see why we can consider $[0,r]$ only. Two questions here. You assume that $y_i \rightarrow y$. We can do this only after we prove that the image of $f$ is bounded using Bolzano Weiestruass theorem right?? The next question is we know $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} f(s_i) = f(s)$ and $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} y_i = y$. The expression $\lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} y_i = \lim_{i \rightarrow \infty} f(s_i)$ because $f(s_i)$ must be one of the image?? Thanks for your answer by the way!

Comment: To show closedness, we need to show that it contains all the limit points. By definition, $y$ is a limit point of the image if there is a seuquence $y_i$ of element in the image so that $y_i \to y$. So $lim y_i =y$ is really an assumption now, and $\lim f(s_i ) = f(s)$ because $s_i \to s$ and $f$ is continuous. @eChung00

Comment: Alright thanks!